# Insertar varias veces un arreglo en la misma hoja

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, array-bidimensional

Estoy desarrollando una macro de Google App Script para insertar varias veces un arreglo en la misma página. El código me inserta una vez pero necesito que me inserte N veces el registro (N es numeroSemana= 53) y no me sobreescriba, o sea que después de insertar la primera vez determine cuál es la última fila y a partir de esa última fila siga insertando

Éste es mi código y me inserta una vez pero no lo sigue haciendo:

```
  function insertarBaseDatos(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let matrizPersonas = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Personas TI'), true).getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(matrizPersonas);
  let ultimaFila= spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Personas TI'), true).getLastRow();
  let numeroSemana= 53;
  let Rango=2;

  //  while(i <ultimaFila ){
  // }
  var contador = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numeroSemana; i++){
      let ultimaFila1= spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BaseDatos_Ej'), true).getRange(2, 1);
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BaseDatos_Ej'), true).getRange('B'+ Rango +':F').setValues(matrizPersonas);
      Rango += ultimaFila1;
  }
}
```

Detalles del mensaje

> Exception: El número de filas de los datos no coincide con el del intervalo. Los datos tienen 999 y el intervalo, 226. (línea 26, archivo "macros")

Comment: Debes utilizar https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents

Comment: Hola Diego, ¿cuál es la pregunta? Tal y como está escrita la publicación no queda claro si tienes un problema o si estás intentando compartir una solución con la comunidad (lo cual está permitido, pero se haría de una manera algo diferente, con la pregunta por un lado y la respuesta por otro). Por favor, completa el [tour] y edita la pregunta para aclarar cuál es el problema que estás encontrando y quieres resolver.

Comment: El tirador tiene que ser acumulable para que cuando vuelvas a escribir sea desde la última línea del registro anterior

Comment: Es que no se como implementar ese acumulador, soy muy nuevo con el mundo de programación y me falta mucho aún para saber mandar un acumulador como parámetro

Comment: acumulador += acumulador

Comment: Detalles del mensaje
Exception: El número de filas de los datos no coincide con el del intervalo. Los datos tienen 999 y el intervalo, 226. (línea 26, archivo "macros")

Comment: No coloques resuelto al título de tu pregunta, con marcar como aceptada una respuesta alcanza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parte del problema es que Google Apps Script no envía los datos a la hoja de manera inmediata. Una solución *rápida y sucia* a tu código es insertar `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` al final del bloque de código del `for` para que en la siguiente iteración `getLastRow()` realmente devuelva la última fila que resulta después de haber agregado nuevos datos a la hoja de cálculo.

---

Lo primero a tener en cuenta es que las llamadas a los métodos de Google Apps Script como `getLastRow` y `getRange` son relativamente lentas por lo que se recomienda usar un algoritmo tal que este tipo de llamadas sean mínimas, más específicamente, en lugar de usar `getLastRow`, `getRange` en un bucle para insertar en cada interación los valores a la hoja de cálculo, usar un `Array` para hacer los cambios y al finalizar el bucle ejecutar una sola vez estos métodos para pasar los datos a la hoja de cálculo.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que al usar en referencias abiertas corres el riesgo de que el `Array` bidimensional devuelto por `getValues` tenga muchas filas con string vacíos. Consecuencias de esto es que si agregas algo al final tendrás muchas filas en blanco intermedias. Una práctica común es usar `getDataRange` lo cual devuelve rango de datos, es decir, desde la primera celda con datos de izquierda a derecha y arriba a abajo hasta la primera celda con datos en la dirección contraria, es decir, de derecha a izquierda y de abajo a arriba.

Si usas `getDataRange` puedes usar `Array.prototype.length` para conocer la posición de `getLastRow` teniendo ello como ventaja que bajo ciertas circunstancias es más rápido.

NOTA: A mí no me gusta usar la grabadora de macros de la hoja de cálculo de Google porque lo que hace es grabar cada activación de hoja y celda (incluye muchos métodos "`setActive`" lo cual generalmente sólo se requiere cuando se hacen las cosas manualmente y resulta innecesario cuando lo que buscamos es ahorrarnos tiempo y esfuerzo).

---

Sobre el código de la rev. 7.

El error ocurre en la línea

`spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BaseDatos_Ej'), true).getRange('B'+ Rango +':F').setValues(matrizPersonas);`

elñ cual se debe a que estas usando referencias abiertas (no hay un número a la derecha de la `F`) así que en la primera iteración está tomando desde la fila 2 hasta la última fila de la hoja, que según el error es 227 filas pero `matrizPersonas` tiene 999.  La solución es que a F le concatenes el el valor de Rango más el número de filas de matrizPersonas menos 1. Cabe mencionar que sería más sencillo que usaras otra la forma de `getRange(filaInicio, columnaInicio, cantidadFilas, cantidadColumnas)`

Por cierto, No deberías poner `let ultimaFila1= spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BaseDatos_Ej'), true).getRange(2, 1);` dentro del for porque sus valores no cambian. Por otro lado, deberías usar `getValue()` de lo contrario la línea `Rango += ultimaFila1;` no va a dar el resultado que pretendes. No te está dando error porque el mensaje de error ocurre en la línea previa.

---

Ejemplo

```
/**
 * Repite los datos un rango en la hoja de destino un número determinado de veces
 *
 */
function repetir() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  /* Tomaomos los valores a repetir */
  var valores = spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1:A3').getValues();

  /* Catidad de veces a repetir */
  var repeticiones = 5;

  /* Hoja de destino */
  var destino = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  /* Aquí pondremos los datos a pasar a la hoja destino */
  var resultado = [];

  /* Iteramos el número de veces que se van a repetir los datos que hemos tomado*/
  for(var i = 0; i < repeticiones; i++){

    /* Agreamos cada una de las filas de los datos a repetir al final de nuestra de resultado */
    valores.forEach(function(fila){
      resultado.push(fila);
    });
  }
  /* Cantidad de filas a pasar */
  var filas = resultado.length;

  /* Cantidad de columnas a pasar */
  var columnas = resultado[0].length;

  /* Posición de la fila inicial */
  var filaInicial = destino.getLastRow() + 1;

  /* Pasamos los datos a la hoja de destino */
  destino.getRange(filaInicial,1,filas,columnas).setValues(resultado);
}
```

Comment: El Flush hacía que la macro fuese más lento pero de igual forma seguía lo mismo, Intenté hacer los cambios con las sugerencias que hizo, pero me retornaba errores por tipo de datos

Comment: @DiegoSanchez El flush(), al igual que otros métodos de Apps Script es lento y  aún más si va dentro un bucle, por eso mencioné que sería una solución `rápida y sucia`. Sobre los otros cambios, te sugiero editar tu pregunta para mostrar lo que has intentado.

Comment: Listo, ya los agregué y me tira error con el rango, dice que hay 226 (el número de filas de todos los registros) y dice que el intervalo tiene 9999 (el tamaño de la hoja)

Comment: @DiegoSanchez He editado mi respuesta.

Comment: @DiegoSanchez He agregado un ejemplo de código que hace lo que estás buscando. Espero puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades particulares.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió perfecto

Answer (score 0):

No comprendo del todo tu código, mas sin embargo te dejo un ejemplo que te podría ayudar es básicamente lo que quieres lograr pero con un ejemplo sencillo.

Simplemente es encerrar tu for en un ciclo while y agregar un contador este contador aumentara siempre que imprima todo tu arreglo.

Ejemplo:
imprimirá un rango de números(0-9) tres veces.

```
contador = 0;
while(contador < 3){
    for (i = 0;i < 10; ++i){
        console.log(" "+i);
    }
        contador += 1;
    }
```

Con tu código:

```
contador = 0;
    while(contador < nCantidadDeRegistros){
  for (i = 0; i < numeroSemana; i++){
    let ultimaFila1= spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BaseDatos_Ej'), true).getLastRow();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BaseDatos_Ej'), true).getRange('B'+ Rango +':F').setValues(matrizPersonas);
    Rango += ultimaFila1;
  }
}
```

Comment: El código es para que inserte y guarde la ultima fila de lo que insertó y en esa misma fila siga insertando