# ¿Cómo usar contadores o ciclos en Google Sheets con Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, macros

//¿Cómo puedo usar un contador o un ciclo en Apps Script para realizar la misma actividad en diferentes hojas? En el código copio la información y la coloco arriba de cada celda, pero si copiará mucha información el código me quedaría muy largo, existe alguna ciclo que me pueda ayudar con las repeticiones?

```
function pptotodoplan() {
  var hoja1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('1-01');
  var hoja2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('1-03');
  var hoja3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('1-04');

  hoja1.getRange('D31:P31').copyTo(hoja1.getRange('D30'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  hoja1.getRange('D53:P53').copyTo(hoja1.getRange('D52'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  hoja2.getRange('D31:P31').copyTo(hoja2.getRange('D30'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  hoja2.getRange('D53:P53').copyTo(hoja2.getRange('D52'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  hoja3.getRange('D31:P31').copyTo(hoja3.getRange('D30'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  hoja3.getRange('D53:P53').copyTo(hoja3.getRange('D52'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En síntesis, no hagas copiar pegar sólo los valores en un ciclo, esto porque es mala idea hacer muchas llamadas a `SpreasheetApp` para copiar los valores de un rango a otros. Si quieres copiar un rango de una posición a otra de la manera más eficiente usa el "Advanced Sheets Service" y más específicamente `batchUpdate`, si no estás listo para usar este servicio, aprende a trabajar por lotes usando matrices bidimencionales y métodos como `Range.setValues(values)` (este último para pasar sólo los valores, necesitarás más para pasar también el formato).

---

En Google Apps Script / JavaScript hay diversas formas de usar "contadores y ciclos", de manera general puedes usar `for` (este tiene varias formas) , `while`, `do`, si vas trabajar con vectores (Arrays) puedes usar Array.prototype.forEach, entre otras tantas.

Lo primero es que te familiarices con el asignación de valores (literales) y objetos, incluyendo fechas, vectores entre otros,  a variables. Si quieres pasar directamente al tema de "contadores y ciclos" lee [Bucles e iteración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), que es parte de las guías de introducción a JavaScript de Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) para que empieces a familiarizarte con el vocabulario.

**Además** en el caso particular de Google Apps Script es importante saber que en el [artículo sobre buenas prácticas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) de la documentación oficial se recomienda usar al mínimo las llamadas a los servicios de esta plataforma ya que estas llamadas son "caras" en términos de tiempo de ejecución, en otras palabras, usar algo como `hoja1.getRange('D31:P31').copyTo(hoja1.getRange('D30'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);` en un ciclo / bucle (en inglés loop) es lento y si los haces decenas de veces sería muy lento e incluso corres el riesgo de exceder el tiempo límite de ejecución, el cual podría ser de 30 segundos, 6 o 30 minutos dependiendo del tipo de cuenta de Google que utilices y de la forma en la que llames tu script.

Recomendaciones

1. Aprende el uso de variables en JavaScript.
2. Aprende el manejo de vectores y matrices en JavaScript.
3. Evita lo más posible hacer `Sheet.getRange()` y particularmente  / `Sheet.getRange()` combinado con `Range.copyTo()` en un ciclo / bucle .
4. Considera sobreescribir todos los valores de la hoja en lugar de sólo hacerlo en rangos específicos cuando sea imperativo reducir el tiempo de ejecución.

Tips

1. `Sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` puedes leer todos los valores de la hoja en una sóla llamada.
2. `Sheet.getRangeList()` permite leer en una sóla llamada varios rangos a la vez.
3. El "Advance Sheets Service" tiene el comando `batchUpdate` con el cual es posible hacer muchos cambios a una hoja de cálculo en una sóla llamada.

Relacionado

- [Cómo optimizar un script para ocultar filas en Hoja de Cálculo de Google, según criterios variables de una columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/201689/65)
- [Insertar varias veces un arreglo en la misma hoja](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/355240/65)
- [Cómo mejorar la velocidad de una función en Google Apps Script que trabaja con muchos registros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/474887/65)

Comment: Exactamente se me presentó el problema que mencionas, al momento de ejecutarlo se vuelve un poco lento y esperaba que con un for se agilizará el proceso. No me quedó muy claro el último párrafo, creo que lo que me tratas de decir es que no use ese código y que lo agilice con los bucles, o me equivoco?             Nada más me queda la duda de como activar varias hojas al mismo tiempo para poder usar el "for", lo que pasa es que hasta ahora solo sé activar una hoja activa a la vez, ya sea por estar en dicha hoja o establecer otra hoja como la activa con getSheetsByName, no sé si se pueda?

Comment: @DanielContreras Edité mi respuesta. Así es, lo que digo es que no uses el código de la pregunta en un ciclo.