# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de una lista de Rangos en Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, macros

// Estoy intentando copiar los valores de mi variable rengeList en el rango que se llama rangeList, pero al momento de copiar los valores solo se pega el primer valor. La idea es que los valores de la fila 31 se peguen en la fila 30, luego como use un ciclo para sumar 22, que los valores de la fila 52 se peguen en la fila 51 y así sucesivamente

```
function obtenerRango() {

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  

  var rengeList = [];
  for (i = 31; i < 600; i += 22) {
    rengeList.push(hoja.getRange(i, 4, 1, 13).getValues());
  }
 
  var rangeList = []
  for (i = 30; i < 599; i += 22) {
    rangeList.push(hoja.getRange(i, 4, 1, 13).getA1Notation());
  }

  hoja.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(rengeList);  
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para copiar los valores de cada rango, simplemente obtén los valores del `i`-ésimo rango con la función `getValues()` y establece la el valor del rango `i - 1` a ese valor con `setValue()`. Puedes optimizar tu código para que sea el doble de rápido incluyendo ambas sentencias en un solo ciclo y evitando tener dos ciclos `for` prácticamente iguales.

Te adjunto una posible solución probada en Google Sheets:

```
function obtenerRango() {

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  for (i = 31; i < 600; i += 22) {
    value = hoja.getRange(i, 4, 1, 13).getValues();
    hoja.getRange(i - 1, 4, 1, 13).setValues(value);
  }

};
```

Comment: Si bien el código es más eficiente en términos de número de iteraciones y líneas que el original, sigue teniendo el mismo problema, aunque con diferente efecto: está usando `setValue cuando debería usar `setValues()`. El efecto  al usar `setValue` es que se "pega" el valor de la primera celda en todas las celdas del rango de destino en lugar de pegar cada uno de los valores de la rango de origen a la posiciones correspondientes.

Comment: En síntesis cambia `setValue` por `setValues` (con **s** al final)

Comment: Tienes razón, mi error. Lo había probado pero con todos los valores iguales. Gracias. Ya agregué la s. No se por qué en mi cabeza, setValue de un rango cuando lo habías extraído de otro rango era equivalente, pero ya veo toma solo el primero. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: No hay de que... yo pasé por lo mismo :)

Answer (score 3):

Sólo "se pega" el primer valor porque el código está usando `setValue`. Para "pegar" todos los valores del Array ( este caso `rengeList`), tendrías que usar `Range.setValues` (con s al final). Entonces, lo primero es obtener de cada uno de los rangos, para esto puedes usar `RangeList.getRanges()` y usar un bucle para aplicar el método `setValues()`. Si encuentras que esto fuera demasiado lento, la forma de reducir el tiempo de ejecución sería usar el "Advanced Sheets Service" y más específicamente `batchUpdate`.

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo usar contadores o ciclos en Google Sheets con Apps Script?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/514332/65)
- [Cómo optimizar un script para ocultar filas en Hoja de Cálculo de Google, según criterios variables de una columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/201689/65)
- [Insertar varias veces un arreglo en la misma hoja](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/355240/65)
- [Cómo mejorar la velocidad de una función en Google Apps Script que trabaja con muchos registros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/474887/65)

Comment: Exacto, pero sí colocó setvalues me arroja un error que dice que no es una función, no sé a qué se deba.

Comment: @DanielContreras actualicé mi respuesta.